# long long initialization and 8 bytes plateform

Tags: c++, assembly, types

I am suprised to discover that under MSVS2012 with x64 plateform as target under debug mode with optimization turn off, a `long long` initialization can't be done in one instruction :

```
; long long l1 = 1;

    mov DWORD PTR _l1$[ebp], 1
    mov DWORD PTR _l1$[ebp+4], 0
```

As register are 8 bytes, I expected a instruction capable of doing it... is there one ?

Comment: There are certainly 64 bit instructions for this. I dontt hav emy x86 reference handy but it's possible that there are short forms of the 32 bit instructions so this combination is shorter or faster. Try it with a very much larger number?

Comment: This very likely has to do with alignment. Moving a quadword to memory can be done atomically provided that it is on a 64bit word boundary. I believe in that case, it uses the MOVQ instruction.

Comment: Well, there's `movq $1, -8(%rbp)`, in intel syntax `mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1` on x64, so it's the compiler.

Comment: Do you have optimization on?  In my tests both initialization and assignment are a single mov instruction.

Comment: Is this under a debug or a release build? Can you show us the code of your test? As others have pointed out there are instructions capable of doing the initialization in one instruction but there might be other factor affecting it.

Comment: I have completed my post: debug mode , optimization turn off

Comment: Well in that case, it looks like an other "optimizations are turned off, why isn't the code optimized?" question.

Comment: oops it seems this is an error on my side. When I reconfigure with plateform manager tool the environnement, I well have `mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8]`

Comment: Also note that particular instruction takes a sign-extended 32 bit immediate, and not full 64 bits. So it works for `1`, but may not work for arbitrary constants.

Comment: My comment is wrong it wouldn't be using ebp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying this in a quick console mode project that targets x64 and looking in the Disassembly window:

```
    long long l1 = 1;
000000013F151035  mov         qword ptr [rsp],1
```

Same code when targeting x86:

```
    long long l1 = 1;
010213EE  mov         dword ptr [l1],1  
010213F5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],0
```

Slam dunk, you are not actually looking at the x64 build of your program.  Use Build + Configuration Manager to fix this.